# MacOS .app files display and behave like folder in windows explorer

Tags: windows, macos, file, format, explorer

I have a spring boot server hosting a product's file distribution and the product has .exe and .app versions. The .exe file is stored and transmitted without issue but the .app file (created from MacOS and transferred into windows via TeamViewer) is displayed as a folder. The server does not recognize it as a file as well and throws

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: source\MyApp.app (Access is denied)
```

When I create a sample text file and save it as test.app it is treated as a file and not a folder. There is no option to change the folder to a file or method to change it's default opening with explorer. I think it does not care about the .app extension and it treats the .app as file name. I tried to zip it and send to windows but it still doesn't work. See the screenshot for what I mean.

[image]

My question is is there any way to change the way windows treats the .app file as a folder? I want it to treat it like a unopenable or raw file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing the extension and treating it as a normal folder (because .app will not allow Java to read from it and I don't know why). Then I read the contents of the file and made it into a zip archive with the extension 'app' and it works correctly.

I am accepting this as a temporary solution but need to find the cause of this problem.